# SED with "#" in a variable

Tags: linux, sed

I have a script that edits header files and replaces some text.

the line of text I want to replace is:

```
#define A MYTEXT
```

I need to do some operations on MYTEXT, so I'm looping through the file to find the string and grab the value:

```
if [[ "$line" == *MYTEXT* ]]
then
  echo $line
  bn=`echo $line| cut -d 'Y' -f 2` #split at the Y value in the string
  #operation here and junk here
  sed 's/'$line$'/'$texttoreplace'/g' HeaderFile.h > out.header.h
fi
done < HeaderFile.h
```

Which works fine for normal strings, however sed is dying with:

```
#define A MYTEXT
sed: 1: "s/#define": unterminated substitute pattern
```

It works fine when I use a file that dosen't a "#" in it, it's just that file.

Any ideas as to what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

#### The Problem

You have a quoting problem. Depending on your settings, Bash will treat anything after an unquoted '#' as a comment.

#### The Solution

You should enclose your sed expression in double quotes, and separate your shell variables from the surrounding text in the expression with braces. For example:

```
line='#define A MYTEXT'
texttoreplace='foo'
echo "$line" | sed "s/${line}$/${texttoreplace}/g"
```

Comment: The solution is correct, but the analysis is not right.  The problem is not the '#' being treated as a comment, but the space in `$line`.

Comment: Also, the shell grammar is much more complex that 'anything after an unquoted # is a comment'.  Consider `echo foo#bar`